# How to animate character grabbing cloth

Tags: cloth-simulation

I've tried to google this with no success.

For example I have a curtain that has cloth sim applied and is slightly billowing in the breeze. A character comes up and pulls the curtain to one side (pinned area at the top of the curtain to remain fixed)

I've tried using hooks but they only seem to work on the pinned parts of the cloth. Collisions are obviously an option but it's so difficult to get the cloth to behave the way you want.

How would you go about animating this?

Comment: Yes, that's the kind of idea. I did work out that one way was to create a duplicate of the baked curtain and apply the cloth to the mesh at the point where the character grabs it. Then bake a the cloth from there with the extra pinned vertices. Then it's just a matter of animated the visibility of the curtains in the timeline.

Comment: Sounds like you fixed it then.  You might consider placing that up as an answer.  In the example where the dummy is opening the curtains, that didn't use cloth physics at all.  A sinewave 'curve' created the vertical folds and shapekeys were used to fold the center edges back.  It eliminated the need for settings, prevented physics fidget, stopped the tendency for ugly shading, and stopped the dropdown elasticity when the cache is activated. The gentle waving in the breeze was basic, slight curtain rotation.  - Happy Blending...  :)